# KVM + Cloudmin + IpTables

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, kvm-virtualization

I have a KVM virtualization on a machine. I use Ubuntu Server + Cloudmin (in order to manage virtual machine instances).

On a host system I have four network interfaces:

```
ebadmin@saturn:/var/log$ ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:78:d2:ec:16:38
    inet addr:192.168.0.253  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
    inet6 addr: fe80::1278:d2ff:feec:1638/64 Scope:Link
    UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:589337 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:334357 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
    RX bytes:753652448 (753.6 MB)  TX bytes:43385198 (43.3 MB)

br1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6e:a4:06:39:26:60
    inet addr:192.168.10.1  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
    inet6 addr: fe80::6ca4:6ff:fe39:2660/64 Scope:Link
    UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:16995 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:13309 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
    RX bytes:2059264 (2.0 MB)  TX bytes:1763980 (1.7 MB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:78:d2:ec:16:38
    UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:610558 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:332382 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
    RX bytes:769477564 (769.4 MB)  TX bytes:44360402 (44.3 MB)
    Interrupt:20 Memory:fe400000-fe420000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
    inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
    inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
    UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
    RX packets:239632 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:239632 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
    RX bytes:50738052 (50.7 MB)  TX bytes:50738052 (50.7 MB)

tap0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6e:a4:06:39:26:60
    inet6 addr: fe80::6ca4:6ff:fe39:2660/64 Scope:Link
    UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:17821 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:13703 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
    RX bytes:2370468 (2.3 MB)  TX bytes:1782356 (1.7 MB)
```

br0 is connected to a real network, br1 is used to create a private network shared between guest systems.

Now I need to configure iptables for network access.

First of all I allow ssh sessions on port 8022 on the host system, then I allow all connections in state RELATED, ESTABLISHED.

This is working ok.

I install another system as guest, it's IP address is 192.168.10.2, and now I have two problems:

1. I want to allow the access from this host to the outside world, cannot accomplish this. I can ssh from the host.
2. I want to be able to ssh to the guest from the outside world using 8023 port. Cannot accomplish this.

Full iptables configuration is following:

```
ebadmin@saturn:/var/log$ sudo iptables --list
[sudo] password for ebadmin:
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8022
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warning

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warning

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warning
ebadmin@saturn:/var/log$ sudo iptables -t nat --list
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:8023 to:192.168.10.2:22

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

The worst of all is that I don't know how to interpret iptables logs. I don't see the final decision of the firewall.

Need help urgently.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a second virtual NIC for the guest which is bridged to `br0` on the host.

Answer (score -2):

Try using the power of SSH! Edit your config:

```
vi ~/.ssh/config
```

---

```
Host saturn
    HostName saturn.yourdomain.com # little shortcut

Host guest1
    ProxyCommand ssh -q saturn nc -q0 guest1.internal.name 22 #(or SSH port)
```

Then, from the outside world, you could do:

```
ssh myuser@guest1
```

And the host will sling you straight in. Don't muck about with iptables for this.